# Python: How to create a loop that depending on values of a list sends sections of a separate file, to one of two output files?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a list with two values, either yes or no. And a sequence which is a list of strings, depending on whether the list says yes or no, I want to send 8 consecutive lines of the sequence file into one of two text files (yes.txt and no.txt) depending on what the list said, and loop this for every item in the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack', what have you tried so far?  
I suggest taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read a little about [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: for i in range(0,len(YesOrNo)):
 a = YesOrNo[i]
 if a == "yes":
  Y.write(sequence[i+7])
 else:
  N.write(sequence[i+7])                                                                  So for the first yes or no in the list i am aiming to take the first 8 lines of the "sequence" file and sends it to either outfile, and then set up a loop so that the 2nd value in list takes the second 8 etc.

Comment: @DB7

I am trying to understand your problem. 
lets say you have something like this  


**YesOrNo** - list of 'yes' or ' no' values inserted into it.  
**sequence** - some list that is an arbitrary sequence of values.  
**Y** - a file object  
**X** - a file object  


You would like to write 8 values from the *sequence* into either file Y or X consecutively based on the values of the *YesOrNo* list?

sorry for all theses edits. the comment format is pretty limited.

Comment: @tockards yes that's exactly what I am struggling with, but it is 8 lines of the sequence document rather than 8 values

Comment: @DB7 we should edit the question above to improve its clarity to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that sequence is a list of lines from a sequence document you could try the following

```
for i in range(0, len(YesOrNo)):
    start = i + (7*i)
    end = 8 * (i+1)
    if YesOrNo[i] == 'yes':
        Y.writelines(sequence[start:end])
    elif YesOrNo[i] == 'no': 
        X.writelines(sequence[start:end])
```

I am using writelines because I am assuming that sequence is list of stings, you could also use write and just replace sequence with `"\n".join(sequence[start:end]`

Comment: That works thank you, it prints all the lines one after another, is there a way to include the "\n" into the command to keep them in the order they were in the original file?

Comment: @DB7 you can achieve that by using `write` method and 
`"\n".join(sequence[start:end])`  replace the lines used for writing to the files with `Y.write("\n".join(sequence[start:end]))` and `X.write("\n".join(sequence[start:end]))` respectively